# ERRO AO DAR PRINTF EM CHAR

Tags: c

Ola,estou tentando fazer uma atividade usando struct,mas na hora de dar printf no valor atribuido a variavel nome ele não exibe nada,alguem pode indicar aonde está o erro ou me dar uma luz ?

```html
/* Program to display Nested Structures in C Programming */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct endereco
{
  char logradouro;
  int numero;
  char bairro;
};

typedef struct
{
  int matricula;
  char nome[20];
  struct endereco add;
}emp3;

emp3 lerData(int matricula, char nome)
{ 
    emp3 c;
    c.matricula = matricula; 
    c.nome[20] = nome;
    return c; 
}
void imprimeData(emp3 emp) 
{
   printf("A matricula armazenada foi: %d\n", emp.matricula);
   printf("O nome armazenado foi: %s\n", emp.nome);

}

int main() 
{
    emp3 emp;
    
 printf("Digite a matricula: ");
    scanf("%d", &emp.matricula);
    printf("Digite o nome: ");
    scanf("%s", &emp.nome);;
    
    emp = lerData(emp.matricula,emp.nome); 
    imprimeData(emp);
    return 0;

}
```

---

não está imprimindo na função imprimiData

Comment: Tem certeza de que seu logradouro e bairro contém um único caractere?

Answer (score 1):

O problema está aqui:

```
emp3 lerData(int matricula, char nome)
{ 
    emp3 c;
    c.matricula = matricula; 
    c.nome[20] = nome;
    return c; 
}
```

Troco por:

```
emp3 lerData(int matricula, char *nome)
{ 
    emp3 c;
    c.matricula = matricula; 
    strcpy(c.nome, nome);
    return c; 
}
```

---

#### Explicação

No seu código você está fazendo a conversão de uma string para caracter: `emp = lerData(emp.matricula,emp.nome);` e atribuído esse caracter a `c.nome[20]` em `lerData` que vai dar um estouro de pilha por a pilha está entre 0 e 19.

o que você deveria fazer é ajustar `lerData` para receber uma string então usando `strcpy` cópia a string para `c.name` em `lerData`.